# Is a single element a Lattice?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

Can a lattice be formed with just a single element? Because for a single element, both Greatest Lower Bound and Least Upper bound exists and is equal to the same element. So can this element be called as a lattice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for every kind of algebra, in the sense of Universal Algebra, i.e., a set endowed with a set of finitely operations, there is a one element algebra, which can be achieved by taking the quotient of that algebra by the universal congruence relation, which is the relation $A^2$ on the algebra  with base set $A$.

Lattices are also algebras is this sense.
(See, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#General_lattice).)
Considering lattices only as ordered structures, we still have one-element lattices, by the exact reason you mentioned.
So, yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Dev5 You're welcome. I understand you are a new user. Here's some useful [information about what to do with helpful answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). It can also apply to the other question you asked before. Good luck!